# Annexes in Ada95

Tags: ada

I want to know the differences between normative and informative annexes in Ada 95.

I am just able to find a list of each of them but not the differences.  What are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *normative* annex specifies what must be true of any Ada implementation providing that Annex.

An *informative* Annex provides additional description or rationale, but places no requirement on Ada implementations.

This is (roughly) the same distinction as between the *Ada Reference Manual* and the *Ada Rationale*.

Comment: So, can i define them this way??Normative Annexes are considered part of the standard.
Informative Annexes are presented for the information provided and are
not considered part of this standard.

Comment: Roughly, yeah -- they're informational material which *accompanies* the standard, but include no requirements.